# Need to retain all columns but getting Duplicate Column Name #1060

Tags: python, mysql

I have this large query I am trying to perform. I perform a series of joins, and then from that resulting relation I want to perform another join and filter out certain tuples.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM
      market_instrument
      inner join exchange_instrument
        on market_instrument.id = exchange_instrument.instrument_id
      inner join Table1 on market_instrument.id = Table1.instrument_id 
      left join Table2 on market_instrument.id = Table2.instrument_id
      left join `options`on market_instrument.id = `options`.instrument_id 
      left join Table3 on market_instrument.id = Table3.instrument_id
  ) as R
  inner join Table4 on R.instrument_id = Table4.instrument_id 
where Table4.fill_timestamp between CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW();
```

`R` is the "series of joins" I'm referring to. I want to `inner join` R with `Table4` and then filter out the resulting relation for the last 30 days (where the date attribute is `Table4.fill_timestamp`). I'm using SQLAlchemy so I thought about somehow saving `R` to some result relation variable and performing a separate query on that, but I don't know how SQLAlchemy handles that, so I wanted to try doing the entire query in SQL first.

I keep getting the Duplicate Column Name "instrument_id" error. `instrument_id` is the primary key for all tables except `market_instrument`, where it's the same but it's called `id` instead. What can I do to get around this issue?

Comment: You've got to specify the table and column in the subquery. E.g. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT Table1.instrument_id,...`

Comment: but I can't possibly list out all the columns that are going to be in the result of the subquery, I need all the columns

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html "Any columns in the subquery select list must have unique names."

Comment: You could try using JOIN ... USING( instrument_id ) - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908249/mysql-removing-duplicate-columns-on-left-join-3-tables. Sorry I don't have time to check & post a full answer.

Comment: what prevents you from listing out all the columns, you said you CANT, or do you mean you DONT WANT TO?

Comment: Each relation has about 7 or more attributes, I'd rather find a better way to do this query without listing every single column. I'm sure finding a way would be beneficial to future visitors to this question who encounter the same problem.

Comment: @PaulF, joining with a `USING` clause solves the ambiguity by not retaining all the columns of the constituent tables.  That's contrary to the OP's desire to retain them all.  Moreover, inasmuch as some of the joins are outer joins, that loss of columns is potentially a genuine loss of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `R` has all the columns from several tables, and more than one of those tables has a column named "instrument_id".  You have not assigned aliases to any of those column names, so SQL does not know which `instrument_id` column you mean when you say "R.instrument_id".

If `market_instrument` is the only table with an `id` column then you could join on `R.id` instead of `R.instrument_id`.

Alternatively, another group of solutions involves assigning different names to some or all of the columns in `R`.  For example,

```
  SELECT
    market_instrument.*,
    exchange_instrument.*,
    Table1.instrument_id AS the_one_true_id,
    Table1.another_column,
    Table1.yet_another_column,
    ...
    Table2.*,
    options.*,
    Table3.*
  FROM
      market_instrument
      inner join exchange_instrument
        on market_instrument.id = exchange_instrument.instrument_id
      inner join Table1 on market_instrument.id = Table1.instrument_id 
      left join Table2 on market_instrument.id = Table2.instrument_id
      left join `options`on market_instrument.id = `options`.instrument_id 
      left join Table3 on market_instrument.id = Table3.instrument_id
```

With the above, you could then join on `R.the_one_true_id`.  Alternatively, you could leave your current join as it is, and rename all the `instrument_id` columns but one.  It might (or might not) be convenient to do that in the context of replacing `R` with a full-fledged `VIEW` in your schema.

Alternatively, your select list could enumerate all the columns of all the tables in the join.  That might be tedious, but if you really do need *all* of them, then you will need to do that to disambiguate the other duplicate names, which include, at least, the various other `instrument_id` columns.  Presented with such a task, however, perhaps you would discover that you don't really need every one of them.

As yet another alternative, you could add more columns instead of renaming existing ones.  For example,

```
  SELECT
    *
    exchange_instrument.instrumentId AS ei_instrument_id,
    Table1.instrument_id AS t1_instrument_id,
    Table2.instrument_id AS t2_instrument_id,
    options.instrument_id AS op_instrument_id,
    Table3.instrument_id AS t3_instrument_id
  FROM
    ...
```

Then you can access, say, `R.t1_instrument_id`, whose name is presumably unique.

Comment: this is great, but by doing `select market_instrument.*, exchange_instrument.*, Table1.instrument_id AS renamed_id ...` would I still be able to retain all columns in the join?

Comment: @JeremyFisher, yes, you can retain all the columns.  You have two options for doing so: (1) in the select list, enumerate all the columns of the table whose column you are renaming, as I attempted to show in my example, or (2) *add* a column with the new name, as I show at the end of my updated answer.