# Confused on ERROR 1060 "Duplicate column name"

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to join multiple tables to have a view that can act as a report, but I'm confused as to why the I'm getting the MySQL ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name 'storeNum'

I have tried using Left Join as from what I understand it looks for the same columns and then joins the tables based on the shared column where the columns that are joined are the ones that differ between the table.

All of the tables are connected by a foreign key.

```
Create view AR_Report as 
select * from AR Left JOIN fullStoreList ON 
AR.storeNumber = fullStoreList.storeNum 
Left JOIN AR_po ON AR.storeNumber = AR_po.storeNum
Left JOIN AR_call ON AR.storeNumber = AR_call.storeNum
Left JOIN AR_prep ON AR.storeNumber = AR_prep.storeNum;
```

```
Create table AR(workOrder varchar(10)  
primary key unique not null, 
storeNumber int UNIQUE, FOREIGN KEY (storeNumber) 
REFERENCES fullStoreList (storeNum));

// where all tables should feed into
```

```
Create table AR_call(storeNum int primary key unique not null, FOREIGN KEY (storeNum) REFERENCES AR (storeNumber), .... );

// AR_call, AR_prep and AR_po start like this
```

```
Create table fullStoreList( storeNum int primary key UNIQUE 
not null, ...);
```

I can post the full create table statements, they are just really long.

I was expecting the view to have all the columns from the other tables be connected by the AR table without the storeNum being present multiple times.

I am very new to MySQL and am just trying to understand it more.

Comment: When you say `SELECT *` it means “every column in every table I join.” If they all have the same name column that is not ok. You’ll have to specify the columns you want and if there are same names you need aliases (though here they have the same value so you just need one of them anyway)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Removing duplicate columns on Left Join, 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908249/mysql-removing-duplicate-columns-on-left-join-3-tables)